# Java multithreading Race condition scenario

Tags: java, multithreading

I was going through the Race conditons in Multithreading and thought of creating a situation which causes race conditions, I wrote a simple program for the same but each time I get the correct result. Need to know if this is correct situation for Race condition.

Code as below:

```
package com.threads;

/**
* demonstrate race conditions
*/

public class Step4 {

public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public void addToA(int number) {

    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
        this.a = this.a + 1;
}

int a = 2;
static Step4 s4 = new Step4();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            s4.addToA(5);
        }
    });

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            s4.addToA(3);
        }
    });

    Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            s4.addToA(6);
        }
    });

    Thread thread4 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            s4.addToA(4);
        }
    });


    thread1.start();    
    thread2.start();    
    thread3.start();
    thread4.start();

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();
    thread4.join();

    System.out.println(s4.getA()); 

}

}
```

//output is 20 always in my machine, Win7 32bit .

Comment: It's very possible that each thread is doing so little work here that they don't overlap at all.

Comment: You are waiting for all 4 threads to complete (join() methods), so of course once the **println** is called, the content is always 20. So no, it does not simulate race condition.

Comment: Make the numbers involved much larger. Race conditions are unpredictable so having each thread spend more time increases the chance of it occuring.

Comment: Here's a version that produces a race condition (at least on my machine): https://gist.github.com/jnizet/5a338e71282a249498ebc14736786c54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program as it is has a very low chance of suffering from race condition, because all threads add to field **a**, so the order does affect the final result.
Only if two threads read the same value of **a**, then first assigns a new value and then the second assigns a new value, you could "lose" an increment.

Here is a modified version that more frequently suffers from race condition:

```
public class Step4 {

  public int getA() {
    return a;
  }

  public void addToA(int number) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
        this.a = this.a + 1;
  }

  public void multiplyA(int number) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.a = this.a * number;
  }

  int a = 2;
  static Step4 s4;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        s4 = new Step4();
        doRun();
        System.out.println("*******");
    }
  }

  private static void doRun() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            s4.addToA(5);
        }
    });

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            s4.multiplyA(3);
        }
    });

    Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            s4.addToA(6);
        }
    });

    Thread thread4 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            s4.addToA(4);
        }
    });


    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();
    thread4.start();

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();
    thread3.join();
    thread4.join();

    System.out.println(s4.getA());

  }

}
```

I've added a 100 ms sleep to both actions, in order to increase the chance of getting different results.
Most times the result will be 31, but might be 17, 21 or 51 on other times.

Comment: It does suffer from a race condition. Two threads can read the current value of a in parallel, then increment it, and you would thus lose an increment.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does simulate a race condition, since the addition involves read and write. But to actually demonstrate the race-ness here, you need some pretty unfortunate scheduling, since all the threads do is addition. You may want to try running this on a different machine, or have some of the threads do other operations, such as devision or subtraction.

Another option is to ensure a race condition by adding a `Thread.sleep(random)` in `addTo()`.